# Decode HTML content of a cloned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, decode

I'm trying to find a way to decode the HTML code of a `div` cloned using jQuery.
The original `div` is dynamically generated by AngularJS variables, and I would like to display its cloned version in a `<pre>` element in order to display the DOM obtained as a result of user input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cloneIt').on('click', function() {
    $('#clone').children().clone().appendTo("pre");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clone" class="hidden">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="language in languages">
        <td class="ico"><img src="assets/images/ico/audio.png"></td>
        <td class="r-text"><a href="assets/audio/{{ language.audio }}.mp3" target="_blank">Ascolta la sintesi in <strong>{{ language.name }}</strong></a></td>
        <td class="ico"><img src="assets/images/ico/pdf.png"></td>
        <td class="r-text"><a href="assets/pdf/{{ language.pdf }}.pdf" target="_blank">Leggi la sintesi in <strong>{{ language.name }}</strong></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<pre class="prettyprint"></pre>

<p>
  <button id="cloneIt" class="btn btn-warning">Generate source code</button>
</p>
```

By pressing the button my desired output (after AngularJS has done its work) should be:

```
&lt;table&gt;   
 &lt;tbody&gt;
    &lt;tr&gt;
      &lt;td class=&quot;ico&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;assets/images/ico/audio.png&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class=&quot;r-text&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;assets/audio/Audio-link_01.mp3&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;Listen to &lt;strong&gt;Italian&lt;/strong&gt; track&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class=&quot;ico&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;assets/images/ico/pdf.png&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class=&quot;r-text&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;assets/pdf/Pdf-link_01.pdf&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;Read &lt;strong&gt;Italian&lt;/strong&gt; transcript&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;/tr&gt;
    [and so on...]
  &lt;/tbody&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
```

How can I decode the HTML content of a cloned `div`?

I am pleased if you can help me in this case. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you required set the `html()` of the `#clone` element as the `text()` of the `pre` element, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cloneIt').on('click', function() {
    $("pre").text($('#clone').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clone" class="hidden">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="language in languages">
        <td class="ico"><img src="assets/images/ico/audio.png"></td>
        <td class="r-text"><a href="assets/audio/{{ language.audio }}.mp3" target="_blank">Ascolta la sintesi in <strong>{{ language.name }}</strong></a></td>
        <td class="ico"><img src="assets/images/ico/pdf.png"></td>
        <td class="r-text"><a href="assets/pdf/{{ language.pdf }}.pdf" target="_blank">Leggi la sintesi in <strong>{{ language.name }}</strong></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<pre class="prettyprint"></pre>

<p>
  <button id="cloneIt" class="btn btn-warning">Generate source code</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I needed: thank you very much indeed! Is it possibile to get rid of annoying Angular generated comments too (e.g.: <!-- ngRepeat: language in languages -->)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery